# Setting global variables from a dictionary within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am looking to use .yaml to manage several global parameters for a program. I would prefer to manage this from within a function, something like the below. However, it seems `globals().update()` does not work when included inside a function. Additionally, given the need to load an indeterminate number of variables with unknown names, using the basic `global` approach is not appropriate. Ideas?

.yaml

```yaml
test:
  - 12
  - 13
  - 14
  - stuff:
      john

test2: yo
```

Python

```
import os
import yaml

def load_config():
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), {file}), 'r') as reader:
        vals = yaml.full_load(reader)
        globals().update(vals)
```

Desired output

```
load_config()

test
---------------
[12,13,14,{'stuff':'john'}]


test2
---------------
yo
```

What I get

```
load_config()

test
---------------
NameError: name 'test' is not defined


test2
---------------
NameError: name 'test2' is not defined
```

Please note: `{file}` is for you, the code is not actually written that way. Also note that I understand the use of global is not normally recommended, however it is what is required for the answer of this question.

Comment: Aside from whether you should mess with globals in this way. Could you outline, what exactly is not working in your example. When trying this myself, I do get the desired output just fine.

Comment: What exactly "does not work"?  Your function does exactly what you say you want in response to my answer. It adds everything in the file to the global namespaces. A spectacularly bad idea that should get you fired - but it works. You are probably running this script in a manner that you're not sharing here, like calling an external Python process. Please provide debugging details on what you're actually doing.

Comment: When I run this (python 3.11) the vars are set local to the function and are not made global. In this sense, I get `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`.  A more thorough investigation shows that they are actually added to globals() meta, but not directly to the dict, aka I can see test in the meta calls, but not the actual output for test (aka test being held in the globals `In` value or `_i3`.

Answer (score 0):

You had `{file}` in your code, I've assumed that was intended to just be a string of the actual filename. I certainly hope you weren't looking to `.format()` and then `eval()` this code? That would be a very bad and unsafe way to run code.

Just return the dictionary `vals` itself, and access it as needed:

```
import os
import yaml


def load_config(fn):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fn), 'r') as reader:
        # only returning the value, so doing it in one step:
        return yaml.full_load(reader)


cfg = load_config('test.yaml')
print(cfg)
print(cfg['test2'])
```

Output:

```
{'test': [12, 13, 14, {'stuff': 'john'}], 'test2': 'yo'}
yo
```

You should *definitely* *never* just update `globals()` with content from an external file. Use of `globals()` is only for very specific use cases anyway.

Getting the exact desired output is just a matter of formatting the contents of the dictionary:

```
import os
import yaml


def load_config(fn):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fn), 'r') as reader:
        return yaml.full_load(reader)


def print_config(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(f'{k}\n---------------\n{v}\n')


cfg = load_config('test.yaml')
print_config(cfg)
```

Which gives exactly the output you described.

Note that this is technically superfluous:

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fn)
```

By default, file operations are executed on the current working directory, so you'd achieve the same with:

```
def load_config(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as reader:
        return yaml.full_load(reader)
```

If you wanted to open the file in the same folder *as the script itself*, consider this instead:

```
def load_config(fn):
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fn), 'r') as reader:
        return yaml.full_load(reader)
```

Comment: Yes, `{file}` was defined for you to input a file name. In my code, I am actually evaluating many files so it is edited for Stackoverflow. 

`You should definitely never just update globals() with content from an external file. Use of globals() is only for very specific use cases anyway.` - This is what I want and I have very specific reasons to do it this way. This is also what is needed to answer this question.

Comment: If you feel your question is answered, consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer., so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: Hey Grismar, after re-reading that I see how that would be confusing. Your answer does not answer the question. I understand your warning on globals, but solving the problem for global is what is specifically needed to receive the check mark and completed answer.